# MySQL: Can't create table with FK getting (errno 150)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

getting ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'at.memdetails' (errno: 150)

```
create table members 
(UserId varchar(5) primary key, 
Name varchar(30) not null, 
UserName varchar(15) not null unique, 
pwd varchar(20) not null);


create table MemDetails (user_id varchar(5) primary key, 
mobileNo bigint not null unique, 
Email varchar(20) not null, 
City varchar(20) not null, 
State varchar(20) not null, 
constraint FKey1 foreign key (user_id) 
references members(user_id) 
on delete cascade);
```

Comment: Both keys are primary auto increment keys. That is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to create 2nd table :

```
create table MemDetails (user_id varchar (5) primary key)
mobileNo BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
Email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
State VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT FKey1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
REFERENCES members(UserId) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```